# Angular: when ran “ng serve”, then error “webpack: Failed to compile.”

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I use mac ox (10.11.6), and tried to learn Angular. I installed node.js, typescript and angular-cli, and every thing works well.

However, when I ran "ng serve", they always popped out the error message“webpack: Failed to compile”. Can somebody help me out?

Qiangs-MacBook-Pro:src qiangcao$ ng serve

> ** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **   10% building modules 5/8 modules 3 active
>   ...s/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js(node:84417)
>   DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string
>   value which can be problematic, see
>   https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56 parseQuery() will be
>   replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
>
> 8083ms building modules                 4ms add0m155ms2550ms asset80ms
>
> emittinggHash: 3f9353293ca829d9b9e1
>
> Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
>
> Time: 11373ms
>               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names    main.bundle.js    2.74 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
>
> styles.bundle.js    9.98 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
>           inline.js    5.53 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
>            main.map    2.79 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
>          styles.map    13.4 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
>          inline.map    5.55 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
>          index.html  485 bytes          [emitted]
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:126:37
>   A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor
>   implementation.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:126:45
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:126:51
>   '=' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:134:45
>   A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor
>   implementation.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:134:55
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:134:61
>   '=' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:29
>   ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:46
>   ';' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:67
>   Cannot find name 'ReadonlyArray'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:89
>   '(' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:91
>   The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:93
>   Cannot find name 'methodName'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:103
>   ']' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:105
>   Cannot find name 'string'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:111
>   ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:112
>   Property assignment expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:120
>   ')' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:123
>   Cannot find name 'ReadonlyArray'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:137
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:143
>   ')' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:143
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:143
>   The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:146
>   Expression expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:148
>   The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:149
>   A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol',
>   or 'any'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:150
>   Cannot find name 'P'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:155
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:161
>   ']' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:161
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:162
>   ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:163
>   Property assignment expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:164
>   Property assignment expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:178
>   ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:179
>   Cannot find name 'P'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:182
>   ':' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:207
>   '{' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:216
>   ':' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:216
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:218
>   Cannot find name 'P'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:221
>   ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:223
>   An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name
>   in strict mode.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:226
>   ':' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:227
>   Expression expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:142:228
>   ';' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:154:41
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:157:57
>   Generic type 'SpyObjMethodNames' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:158:60
>   Generic type 'SpyObjMethodNames' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:160:39
>   Generic type 'SpyObjMethodNames' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:161:42
>   Generic type 'SpyObjMethodNames' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:198:21
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:198:34
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:575:12
>   Invalid use of 'arguments'. Modules are automatically in strict mode.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:8
>   A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol',
>   or 'any'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:9
>   Cannot find name 'k'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:14
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:20
>   ']' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:20
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:21
>   ';' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:22
>   Declaration or statement expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:24
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:26
>   Cannot find name 'k'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:29
>   ';' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:48
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:50
>   Cannot find name 'k'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:55
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:61
>   Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:635:63
>   Cannot find name 'k'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:642:23
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:644:31
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:646:40
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:648:32
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:650:33
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:652:16
>   Cannot find name 'Spy'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:691:36
>   Cannot find name 'Reporter'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:697:20
>   Cannot find name 'RunDetails'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:701:18
>   Cannot find name 'Suite'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:702:32
>   Cannot find name 'SuiteOrSpec'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:711:14
>   Cannot find name 'Spec'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:712:15
>   Cannot find name 'Clock'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:716:29
>   Cannot find name 'HtmlReporter'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:717:31
>   Cannot find name 'HtmlSpecFilter'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:720:0
>   Declaration or statement expected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:725:25
>   Module
>   '"/Users/qiangcao/angular2_hello_world/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index".jasmine'
>   has no exported member 'Jasmine'. Child html-webpack-plugin for
>   "index.html":
>            Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
>       index.html  2.94 kB       0        webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: you ran `ng server` or `ng serve`?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I ran ng serve

Comment: i would do `npm uninstall @types/jasmine` and then `npm i @types/jasmine`... else, kindly update the question with output of `ng -v`

Comment: @AkberIqbal I did these two commands, however, still have error. And the output of "ng -v":  angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.18
node: 10.15.3
os: darwin x64

Comment: you have a deprecated version of angular (ref:https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli/v/1.0.0-beta.18)... `npm uninstall @angular/cli` then `npm install @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: @AkberIqbal thanks, it works. However, because I want use the old version, how to fix the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments above:

- You have a deprecated version of angular (ref:npmjs.com/package/angular-cli/v/1.0.0-beta.18)... npm uninstall @angular/cli then npm install @angular/cli@latest

on your comment about **getting the old angular/cli version to work**:

- The old version *might not work with newer npm and node*... if you really want to get the old version working, i'd suggest go to a test machine and install relevant npm and node and angular/cli versions of the same time period as angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.18